# jquery : how to get sender button id inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have  four button on my application. Each of the buttons call the same javascript function say "Hello Me". when calling this "Hello Me" function, I want to set the hidden field value to different. Like if button one is called this function should set hidden field value to "Hello 1" if button two clicked than "hello 2 " so on an so forth.

I am trying to get the sender button id  inside "Hello Me" function but not sure how to do it?Is there anyway to get sender button id inside "Hello me function"? I am trying to achieve this using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this);">

function myFunction(button)
{
    var myButton = $(button);
    window.alert(myButton.attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the information as a data attribute to each button and then look that data up using jQuery:

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" data-number="1">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(this).data("number");  // equals "1" if the above button is selected.
```

----------------------- edit -----------------------

If you really want to use the id attribute though, you can use:

```
$(this).attr("id");   // equals whatever id you gave this button
```